# How to get the location of control by mouse click if I want to use the same click event for all objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the location of sender by mouse click event.

Is there any way I can get it, if I use the same mouse click event for all the objects?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, wath you have to do is attach your method method_Click() to all controls in your form. For example:

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    x.Click += method_Click;
}
```

P.D. Don't forget cast your sender as a Control ;)

```
private void method_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = (Control)sender;
    int x = ctrl.Location.X;
    int y = ctrl.Location.Y;
}
```